# How can I install Google Play on Raspberry Pi Zero W?

Tags: pi-zero

I am working on a smartwatch that uses a Raspberry Pi Zero W, and I want to be able to download Google Play on it to impress my friends and play some very simple games. If so, does it have touchscreen support? I am trying to do this on Raspbian with a 32 gigabyte SD card. (please use download links if available) Plus, will Google Play overheat the Pi?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/android-raspberry-pi/ with the caveat there is no touch screen support. Says it plays Angry Birds though and installs things from the play store. Was a year ago. This sounds a fairly ambitious project though.

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot install Google Play on Raspbian** — Google Play only works on Android. It's the exact same reason why your Windows PC can't have Google Play installed — they just aren't compatible at all. While Android is based on the Linux kernel, just like Raspbian, the similarities end there.

It is unlikely that Android will ever be ported to the Pi Zero, so you can't simply run Android instead, according to [the Google Group 'android-rpi'](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/android-rpi/zero%7Csort:date/android-rpi/LWRCAQ7mQmg/QvUPEzQIAQAJ):

> Completely different architecture: the Pi Zero is ARMv6 and the Pi 3 is ARMv8 (although we run it at ARMv7).
>   The Pi Zero will probably never see any Android build because the architecture used for the CPU is just so old.

This unfortunately means you're out of luck. You might be able to [emulate other games](https://retropie.org.uk/forum/topic/3934/what-emulators-can-the-pi-zero-run-well/2), but the Pi Zero is just too underpowered to run Android, and there aren't any images available. Even the more beefy Pi 3 struggles to run Android perfectly.

Comment: Google Play could absolutely be compatibility. But it isn't. Android runs on various systems. It is open source, after all. But it doesn't because of business and user experience reasons. Google makes money on its devices. And applications that run poorly (at least in theory), it could harm Android name and lose confidence. Again. Google makes money on Android. So it would pretty much be be stealing. Or I don't doubt violating some terms of agreement.